# SQL Server Service Broker and Linked Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, service-broker

I've setup a Service Broker on one of databases to automatically pick up stored procedures in a specific schema (Build) and run them on a daily basis. So far everything has been running fine, however we've now got a need where we need to access a remote sql server which is running SQL Server 2017 and has the latest Machine Learning Service installed.

I've given the service account that runs the primary SQL Server (SQL 2016) access on the remote server, and ensured the Service Broker is executing under the service account, rather than the local SQL account (sa).

Whenever we try to access the remote server, we are getting the following error:

> Linked servers cannot be used under impersonation without a mapping
>   for the impersonated login.

I've tried adding an EXECUTE AS to the process, however this doesn't seem to make a difference. I've also ensured it is running under the service account, and it is.

I can get it to work using a mapped login on the linked server, however this isn't ideal, as we don't want to run the sql server in mixed authentication as this has been determined as an IT risk.

I've run out of ideas or what I can do here, and can't find any other help pieces with this same problem. I did want to roll this process out to more of our warehouse builds, however this is a deal breaker at this stage.

help?

Comment: The error says that you did not map Win account used as login on the first server on the second server

Comment: I'm not entirely following your need for a linked server. Specifically, can you send a Service Broker message to the remote server instead, have it do whatever and send back a response?

Comment: I'm wanting to not have to setup a mapping, and for it to simply use the account that it is running under, as it has access to the remote server.

Comment: In terms of sending a message to the remote server, that is definitely an option, it would require additional setup. Currently we have service broker running on one server which picks up all the stored procedures in a certain schema, and runs them once a day. One of the stored procedures requires access to a remote server to use the upgraded Machine Learning server, however even if I simply want to access data on the remote server, I get the same error.